# Which command should I use to make .jpeg from .flv using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, flv

The below command creates jpeg out of .mpg, but fails to create jpeg out of .flv.

How can I do that?

```
$ffmpegpath = FFMPEG_PATH;
$input = "video_file/orig/fdgdf.mpg";//Lady.flv";
$output = "video_file/thumb/kuni.jpeg"; 

$command = "$ffmpegpath -i $input -an -ss 00:00:$fromdurasec -r 1 -vframes 1 -s 80x80 -f mjpeg -y $output";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y %d.jpg
```

[source](http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2006/4/25/ffmpegthumbs)

Comment: No its not working

Comment: Ipsita was probably using an outdated version of ffmpeg, the command here does indeed work perfectly well.